# Three.js "Fragment shader is not compiled" error when using flat shading

Tags: three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I'm loading a model in three,js using GLTFLoader.  It works fine, except I'm trying to use flat shading.  If I set flatShading = true, I get an error saying that the fragment shader is not compiled.  Here is the code I'm using to load the model:

```
function loadModel() {
    // Load the model
    gltfLoader.load(modelPath + '.gltf', function (gltf) {
        for (let i = 0; i < gltf.scene.children.length; i++) {
            // Skip bones
            if (gltf.scene.children[i].isBone) {
                continue;
            }

            // If a mesh has multiple segments, then it is a group with an array of children (segments/meshes)
            // If a mesh only has one segment, then it is a single object (mesh) with no children, not an array of length 1
            let numSegments = gltf.scene.children[i].isGroup ? gltf.scene.children[i].children.length : 1;
            for (let j = 0; j < numSegments; j++) {
                let mesh = gltf.scene.children[i].isGroup ? gltf.scene.children[i].children[j] : gltf.scene.children[i];

                mesh.material.flatShading = true;
                //mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
            }
        }

        // Show the model
        scene.add(gltf.scene);

        }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

If I omit the flatShading line, the model loads fine.  However, with the flatShaing included, I get the following error message:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: Shader Error 0 - VALIDATE_STATUS false

Program Info Log: Fragment shader is not compiled.


FRAGMENT

ERROR: 0:1233: 'vTBN' : undeclared identifier


  1228:     normal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
  1229: #elif defined( TANGENTSPACE_NORMALMAP )
  1230:     vec3 mapN = texture2D( normalMap, vUv ).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0;
  1231:     mapN.xy *= normalScale;
  1232:     #ifdef USE_TANGENT
> 1233:         normal = normalize( vTBN * mapN );
  1234:     #else
  1235:         normal = perturbNormal2Arb( - vViewPosition, normal, mapN, faceDirection );
  1236:     #endif
  1237: #elif defined( USE_BUMPMAP )
  1238:     normal = perturbNormalArb( - vViewPosition, normal, dHdxy_fwd(), faceDirection );
  1239: #endif
```

I am using revision 143.

I'm a noob at 3D modeling, so I don't really understand what this error means.  If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show both `shaders`?

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/26197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is a bug in older versions of `three.js`. When flat shading is enabled and geometry tangents are present, there is a shader compilation error.

It has been fixed since  `r154`.

If you can't upgrade your `three.js` version, traverse through the scene and remove all `tangent` buffer attributes from the geometries via the following line when using flat shading:

```
geometry.deleteAttribute( 'tangent' );
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets rid of the error.  However, with flatShading = true, the model still appears smooth.  I may have to try to upgrade to a newer version of three.js and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Update: I figured out the flatShading issue.  I was using ambient lighting, but I guess that doesn't allow the faces to be seen.  I added a hemisphere light, and now the faces are visible.